# How to change a Git commit's encoding header?

Tags: git, encoding, header, commit

Is there a way in Git to rewrite the `commit encoding` header? I have some commits with an `author name` which has `ISO-8859-1` encoded name but the commit encoding header is empty, which defaults to `UTF-8`. This leads some applications to error (eg. Gitlab) on decoding the commit. Same applies to some commit messages.

Some ideas?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to actually use UTF-8 in those fields?

Comment: Pracitically yes. Generally it should be safe either way. UTF-8 with default header or other encoding with repectiver header field.

Comment: Sidenote: It was caused by a Solaris user. Solaris has `ISO-8859-1` standard encoding. The user.name included a german _Umlaut_ *ä*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
$ git filter-branch -f --commit-filter '
author_type=$( echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME | file -b --mime-encoding - )
author=$( echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME | iconv -f $author_type -t UTF-8 )
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$author

committer_type=$( echo $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME | file -b --mime-encoding - )
committer=$( echo $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME | iconv -f $committer_type -t UTF-8 )
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$committer

git commit-tree "$@";' --msg-filter '
cat > .commitmsg
type=$(cat .commitmsg|file -b --mime-encoding -)
cat .commitmsg|iconv -f $type -t UTF-8
' HEAD

$ rm -f .commitmsg
```

Answer (score 2):

If the commit messages are really messed up and Sascha's solution does not work (because `file -b --mime-encoding -` does not tell the truth), one can use the following to get rid of every character in the commit messages that is not ASCII:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter '
  perl -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g;'
  ' HEAD
```

Clearly, this is far from being perfect since it kills every kind of non-english characters like umlauts, but in some circumstances (i.e. a git-repo that results from old cvs-repo with terribly encoded commit messages) it might be the only automatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Testing (with git 2.2.0) shows that `git commit` adds `encoding <blah>` to the commit headers whenever you do a new commit with `i18n.commitencoding = blah`.  This includes "amended" commits—which are just new commits whose parent(s) is/are `HEAD`'s parent(s)—so, given an existing commit that you wish to mark that is at `HEAD`, simply run `git commit --amend` and exit the editor to write a new (different) `HEAD` commit with the additional header line.

I did not test `git rebase -i` but since that runs actual cherry-pick operations, and `edit` mode allows you to use `git commit --amend` to make a new `HEAD` commit, it will certainly work.  The mechanics may not be the prettiest.

To see a raw commit (including its encoding line) use `git cat-file -p HEAD` (or some other commit-ID in place of `HEAD`).

(As eis notes [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959487/how-to-change-a-git-commits-encoding-header#comment46173208_28959487), it's probably better to use UTF-8 in the first place.  You can of course do this as the amend process, although it may—or may not—be tricky depending on your editor.)

Comment: I am speaking about approximately 2600 commits, so I am seeking for some automatism way to do this. Like filter-branch --commit-filter. Yet no success